# Influxdb - Count of measurement data

Tags: influxdb

I have the following query for a measurement:

```
select foo from myMeasurement
```

which returns something like this:

```
time                 foo
----                 ----
123412341234123412   valOne
123412341234123413   valOne
123412341234123414   valOne
123412341234123415   valTwo
123412341234123416   valTwo
123412341234123417   valThree
123412341234123418   valThree
123412341234123419   valThree
123412341234123420   valThree
```

I would like to get the count of each one.  In other words I would like to get the following

```
foo        numResults
---        ----------
valOne     3
valTwo     2
valThree   4
```

I have tried using select count(*) and group by foo, but I can't seem to get the correct syntax/combination to generate the desired results.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Unrelated: I explained to you why your questions were closed, and that your assumption "this community is supposed to give me answers that exactly match my current skills" is flawed. Again, this place is not a free tutoring forum where people fine tune things individually just for you; at least not when asking about such topics that mostly require you to spend the time it takes to learn the corresponding context. Thing is: if you want to use regular expressions that you don't understand ... then there are no detours. Then you have to step back and LEARN the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `foo` field marked as a tag? The `GROUP BY` sentence doesn't work in any kind of field. It's not like in a relational database where you can easily `GROUP BY` by any field.

In this case the `foo` field should be marked as a tag field.

You can check the following documentation: [GROUP BY tags](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/explore-data/#group-by-tags)

A little bit above you can see the following description:

> Note: You cannot use GROUP BY to group fields.

Once you have it you can execute the same query and it will work.